Can two drums almost sound the same?
Let $D\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a region and let $\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots\}$ be the set of eigenvalues of the Laplacian $-\Delta$ (with boundary condition $\psi=0$ on $\partial D$).
Mark Kac, in his famous article Can One Hear the Shape of a Drum?, only considers asymptotics of the function $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}e^{-\lambda t}$ as $t\to0^+$, hence cannot detect if finitely many $\lambda_i$'s are modified. This lead me to wonder:

Can there be two planar regions $D_1$ and $D_2$ with Laplace eigenvalues $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$, respectively, such that there exists a $\lambda>0$ such that $\Lambda_1\cap\mathbb R_{>\lambda}=\Lambda_2\cap\mathbb R_{>\lambda}$ but $\Lambda_1\ne\Lambda_2$? In other words, can two regions be "almost" isospectral without actually being isospectral?


I don’t know if $\lambda\approx 0$ correspond to low or high wavelength tones, but if it is high wave-length you could rephrase this as drums that young people can distinguish, but old people cannot.

@MarkSchultz-Wu unfortunately small frequency corresponds to low tones.

"Obviously", the answer must be yes, since (equally famously) they can sound exactly the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum#The_answer

@ChristianRemling I don't understand, that satisfies the condition $\Lambda_1\cap\mathbb R_{>\lambda}=\Lambda_2\cap\mathbb R_{>\lambda}$ but it does not satisfy $\Lambda_1\ne\Lambda_2$.

@KentaSuzuki: It is not a formal argument (hence the scare quotes). What you are asking for feels easier than having the eigenvalues agree completely.

@ChristianRemling On the other hand, it is possible for two distinct number fields to have the same zeta function but it is not possible to have the same zeta function except for finitely many Euler factors and then have those Euler factors different.

For locally symmetric spaces of rank $1$ (in particular for hyperbolic manifolds) this is not possible (but isospectral non-isometric examples exist).

@Aurel do you have a reference for this fact?

Sure: Cor 1 of this paper, see also Thm 1 of that paper for a refinement where infinitely many different eigenvalues are allowed but of low enough density.
